# Customer Error: Failed to load csv data with exception. Deduced delimiter ',' is not found in the line

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-sagemaker

We're using AWS SageMaker to train a shop-assistant-bot... well, at least we're trying.

```
xgb.fit({'train': s3_input_train})
```

After the setup done following [the tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/it/getting-started/hands-on/build-train-deploy-machine-learning-model-sagemaker/) until Step 3, we tried starting the training with the method `fit`.

That's were problems started...

```
2023-06-22 13:29:21 Starting - Starting the training job...
2023-06-22 13:29:36 Starting - Preparing the instances for training......
2023-06-22 13:30:30 Downloading - Downloading input data...
2023-06-22 13:31:11 Training - Training image download completed. Training in progress...
```

...the first part went smooth, but then we encountered this `[INFO]`s.

```
[2023-06-22:13:31:29:INFO] Running standalone xgboost training.
[2023-06-22:13:31:29:INFO] Path /opt/ml/input/data/validation does not exist!
[2023-06-22:13:31:29:INFO] File size need to be processed in the node: 0.03mb. Available memory size in the node: 55595.48mb
[2023-06-22:13:31:29:INFO] Determined delimiter of CSV input is ','
```

Still they're like warnings, no problem, but suddenly we got this error...

```
[2023-06-22:13:31:29:ERROR] Customer Error: Failed to load csv data with exception:
b"[13:31:29] src/data/csv_parser.h:124: Deduced delimiter ',' is not found in the line. Expected ',' as the delimiter to separate fields.
```

The error was much longer, the full traceback is at the end of [this](https://github.com/FLAK-ZOSO/SageMaker/blob/a474a314635be4e0d47bd78cbadb0573c99377b4/Armani.ipynb#L1259) backup of the Notebook, I strongly suggest to see it in preview-view on GitHub anyway.

---

The `.csv` loaded is [this one](https://github.com/Leonardo-Michelazzo/LLama-AI/blob/main/categorizzatore/Armani.csv), exported from a Google Sheet.

We did some operations on it before that point in the code since we first loaded it this way...

```
model_data = pd.read_csv('./products.csv', index_col=0)
```

...and then splitted it this way...

```
train_data, test_data = np.split(model_data.sample(frac=1, random_state=1729), [int(0.7 * len(model_data))])
```

...and then uploaded it to s3 bucket this way...

```
train_data.to_csv(
   'train.csv',
    index=False,
    header=True
)
boto3.Session().resource('s3').Bucket(bucket_name).Object(
    os.path.join(
        prefix, 'train/train.csv'
    )
).upload_file('train.csv')
```

I'm quite sure there's something wrong in our way of handling the dataframe, but then I don't get why it's only the last code cell failing.

---

I found [this correlated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51635902/aws-sagemaker-unable-to-parse-csv) but it didn't clarify the situation that much.

Does anybody have a bare idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked if the CSV actually uses commas (`,`) as a delimiter? Maybe the export from the Google sheet has used something else.

Comment: @DennisTraub I thought about it but... https://github.com/Leonardo-Michelazzo/LLama-AI/blob/main/categorizzatore/Armani.csv see the source, it's a CSV for real, it uses commas.

Comment: I believe XGBoost requires numeric values.. "We use the Abalone dataset, originally from the UCI ML repository. In this libsvm converted version, the nominal feature (Male/Female/Infant) has been converted into a real valued feature as required by XGBoost. " from https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/xgboost_abalone/xgboost_abalone_dist_script_mode.ipynb

Comment: @durga_sury so what could I do to fix this? Since both my columns and my values are strings.

Comment: You'll have to pre-process the dataset accordingly, one-hot encode values, remove strings if they're not adding value etc. You can use python packages, or Data Wrangler to make these transformations on the Studio UI too.